# How to adjust scrollbar in dropdown list when corners are rounded?

Tags: css

I am new to css and html so forgive me if the question is too simple.
I have a dropdown list which is designed with this css:

```
.open > .dropdown-menu {
  display: block; 
  height:170px;
  border-radius: 22.5px;
  border: solid 2px #a1a1a1;
  overflow:auto;
  margin-top:-55px;
  width:-webkit-fill-available; 
}
```

The problem is that the scrollbar is a rectangle, and on the corners it just goes out the dropdown borders.
How can I adjust my scrollbar such that it would fit inside the dropdown list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can only style the scrollbar for Chrome browser. I would advice to add some padding to the element

Answer (score 0):

I suggest below trick. You can of course adjust values and change styles, but general idea is shown below. Trick is to wrap dropdown in wrapper with `overflow: hidden`, so it's child's scrollbar is partially hidden.

#### Snippet

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container:hover .dropdown-wrapper {
  display: initial;
}

.dropdown-wrapper {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 30px;
}


.dropdown {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Hover me
  <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
    <div class="dropdown">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```